# Multiplying Binomial Terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(x+2)(x-1$)

Totally forgot how to do it.
Isn't this the rule:

$(a+b)(c+d)$

$a*c +a*d +b*c +b*d$

The answer I'm getting is $x^2-x+2x-2$ which is wrong.
Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: One mnemonic that might also help you recall how to multiply binomials (two terms in parentheses) is FOIL: First terms: $x^2$; Outer terms: $-x$; Inner terms: $2x$; Last terms: $-2$. The key fact to remember, as you do above, to *distribute$ each value of one term by multiplying it with each of the values of the second term (which can be generalized to non-binomial factors).

Comment: Personally, I find FOIL rather foolish (or "foilish", perhaps?) a mnemonic; distributivity is better, and less likely to confuse the student when you need to multiply binomial by a trinomial, or more complex expressions...

Comment: yes, indeed, "foil"-ish! I agree that emphasizing distributivity is more generalizable.  "FOIL" can simply be a reminder of the need to distribute multiplication, for those who insist, e.g., that $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not wrong. You just haven't noticed that $-x+2x = x$, so that, if you *simplify*, you get
$$(x+2)(x-1) = x^2 -x + 2x - 2 = x^2 + x - 2.$$

Comment: I see, thanks for helping out, finally I can continue my studies. Appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 4):

The FOIL "rule" (First, Outer, Inner, Last) simply follows from the [distributive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributivity) laws:

$$k(m+n) = km + kn$$

$$(k+m)n = kn + mn$$

In your case,

$$
\begin{align}
(x+2)(x-1) = x(x-1) + 2(x-1) = x^2 - x + 2x - 2 = x^2 + x - 2,
\end{align}
$$

as you have already noted.

Comment: Well, to be strictly accurate, you also need commutativity — or, equivalently, the law that $(m+n)k = mk + nk$ (which is what you used in the first step).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Thanks for the comment.  I edited my answer accordingly.